# Playwright & Vite - test block cannot find an element, although exists

Tags: reactjs, vite, playwright

I'm running some e2e tests with `playwright` with `vite` frontend application.
This is my code:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test.describe('Auth page @auth-page', () => {
    test('auth page should have brand logo', async ({ page }) => {
        await page.goto('http://localhost:8080/');

        const isBrandLogoElementVisible = await page.locator("[data-test-id='auth-brand-logo']").isVisible();

        expect(isBrandLogoElementVisible).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

I run this script: `playwright test -c ./playwright.config.ts`

When I run the test the output is

```
basic/auth.spec.ts:4:6 › Auth page @auth-page › auth page should have brand logo ==============

    Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

       7 |              const isBrandLogoElementVisible = await page.locator("[data-test-id='auth-brand-logo']").isVisible();
       8 |
    >  9 |              expect(isBrandLogoElementVisible).toBe(true);
         |                                                ^
      10 |      });
      11 |
      12 |      test('auth page should have main header', async ({ page }) => {
```

But, when I run `playwright test -c ./playwright.config.ts --debug` it succeeds. I guesss it's because the test waits for my inputs on debug mode and then the element start rendering.
How can I change it to work?

I Expect Playwright to find the element as it exists

Comment: Can you try `await expect(page.locator("[data-test-id='auth-brand-logo']")).toBeVisible()` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-is-visible), `page.locator(...).isVisible()` does not wait for the element to become visible. The recommended way to do this is to use `expect(page.locator(...)).toBeVisible()` which [does wait for a specific, configurable amount of time](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible).

```
await expect(page.locator("[data-test-id='auth-brand-logo']")).toBeVisible()
```